# Schema DB querying with Mongo Db. I don't understand why but the way I call to push or retrieve data from the db it seems to time out and throw err

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm very new to MERN so I'm trying to figure out how to use schema correctly within my backend. I'm trying to just make a very simple case here where I just create a new user document in the database. I'm not trying to do anything with auth yet I just want to figure the syntax i guess behind why my code is not communicating correctly with the db.
When I run my backend code it says I successfully am running on port 4000 and that I've connected to my database.
When I check my routes with Postman it seems to time out and return bad request.

Here is my Schema code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    balance: {type:Number, required:true},
    currentLimit: {type:Number, required:true},
    maximumLimit: {type: Number, required:true, default:50}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

This is where I make the call to the database in my router function

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../Models/user');
const userInfo = express.Router();

userInfo.route('/userInfo').get(
    async function (req, res) {
        await User.find().then((err, results) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(result);

        })
    }
);

userInfo.route('/makeUser').post(
    async function (req, res) {
        const { name, balance, currentLimit, maximumLimit } = req.body;
        try {
            const user = await User.create({ name, balance, currentLimit, maximumLimit });
            res.status(200).json(user);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json(error);
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
);
module.exports = userInfo;
```

This is my connection code

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const Db = process.env.URI;
const client = new MongoClient(Db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

module.exports = {
    connectToDatabase: async function (callback) {
        try {
            client.connect();
            console.log('Succesfully Connected to Database');
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my index file

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config({path: "./config.env"});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(require('./routing/userInfo'));
const dbo = require("./DB/connection");


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
    dbo.connectToDatabase(function (err){
        if (err) console.error(err);
    })
    
})
```

I feel like I've read so many mongodb schema docs and I do exactly as the docs say but still fail to read or write to/from the db.

Comment: Are you sure the endpoints are working?

Comment: @AnılhanHasceviz how exactly would I check for that?

Comment: It looks like the problem is not in mongodb. Because as you said, you got a timeout error. So you accepted the request but didn't response. Can you write a plain endpoint without mongo db in it and try to see if there is an response?

Comment: @AnılhanHasceviz I just wrote a function that should respond with data = {name:'justin'} and tested in postman and it worked. So my endpoints are working I assume.